# extract data from javascript multidimentional arrays

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I'm having an ajax call that returns nested arrays

```
success: function(data, el){
console.log(data);
```

Here's the data

[image]

I need to extract the [name] value from [metas] I've tried this

```
data[1][0][3]
```

but the result is 'undefined'

Comment: Please post data as JSON, not as an image of a PHP value.

Comment: that's the whole data i get when i use console.log(data)

Comment: Wait, that's a clientside log? Then you really need to work on your serialisation. What you currently have is a string, with no quick way for JavaScript to parse into anything.

Comment: A string? What a great serialization it would be. Look at the indentation and whitespaces!

Comment: I'm using this image upload script http://filer.grandesign.md/and all what i've done is added console.log(data); in the custom.js file line 84 to get new image name to use it in the webpage

Answer (score -1):

Associative array, try:

```
data['metas'][0]['name']
```